# How do I optimize BLE transfer speed on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android app which receives data from a hardware device using Bluetooth Low Energy. The device sends a specific number of bytes each time but when the app receives this data, some bytes are lost in between at random. There is no pattern in which bytes are lost.

Please suggest a round about to handle the rate at which I am receiving data or how I can optimize the speed at which the Android phone receives data.

Comment: What is the time interval at which the data is transmitted from the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot change transfer/receiving intervals from Android BLE API (At least not yet).

If you can program the sensor, you can try changing connection parameters, slave latency in particular. Minimum (if I remember correctly) is 7.5 milliseconds. But, please, do bear in mind, BLE is not meant for transmitting big amounts of data.

**Extra information:**
If minimum slave latency is 7.5 ms and you can transmit 20 bytes per transmissions, your maximum throughput is 2.5Kb/s (1000/7.5 * 20).

Comment: Thank you, but what do you think would be the maximum amount of data that can be transferred? We are looking at a data rate of 8Kb/s. Would that be possible

Comment: I have managed to achieve transmit rates about 8KBytes/s using two Android 6 devices as peripheral & central and sending data through notifications and unreliable (non-ACK) writable characteristic. Notice: Android seems to negotiate high ATT_MTU of 517 (which gives 514 payload) bytes by default. Still, it is ATT MTU, and the message gets broken into 23 bytes at lower level, anyway. BLE 4.2 offers new mechanisms to actually have larger MTU sizes at the lower levels, but it is not widely supported yet. So, for now 2.5 - 12 KB/s is the expected bandwidth range with mainstream devices.